# Allow a user to not only input multliline text but move up and edit previously entered lines

Tags: c++, file, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, text-editor

Im working on a crude console based text editor in C++ kind of like nano. I've already figured out a basic way of inputting multiple lines of text and writing it to a file correctly (input ends when they enter a code: `//end`). However, at the moment the user is unable to move upwards (using arrow keys) and edit lines that they have entered. For some additional information I'm doing this with a `getline()` loop, writing files with `ofstream`, and am storing the users text in a string `vector` with each element being an entered line. How might I implement the ability to work with a body of text in such a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For advanced use, you need access to the console API.

For a simpler version, look at the primitive visual editors.

Editing a line consists of moving to the line, printing out the content, and then letting them insert or delete characters on that line.

Look at sed or ed or even vi.

Comment: Okay, do you know what API sections/items I would need to make use of?

Comment: @CipherVisor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition and such?  There are probably many libraries that will solve piles of corner cases for you, however.